# SPSS Aggregating data from another dataset

Tags: spss

I'm making a SPSS syntax. I have two datasets. One of the individuals, the other consisting of their groups. I have aggregated the mean of individuals in that active dataset. However, I need to have this constant in the other, the groups dataset. So that I can compare group means with the overall mean. Please help.

Comment: This a data management question, not statistical. You should merge the 2 datasets (see Data - Merge Files)

Comment: Although this is on the face of it more suited to Stack Overflow, "please give me some code" questions are not always welcomed there. There may be an SPSS forum that is supportive of such questions, but I can't advice.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment [MATCH FILES](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/topic/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_match_files_overview.htm) command will help you to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the "insert" command which generates syntax for you?